# Detect if customer already exists when placing an order from admin

Tags: magento2

Can I implement an ajaxcheck that will fire as soon as the email address is entered when an order is placed for a new customer from the admin in Magento 2? This is meant as a safeguard for placing an order for a customer that already exists.

Currently, the check will happen after the 'Submit Order' button is pressed and if the customer exists all the order information needs to be input again after selecting that customer from the customer grid.